# Context interpolation for env vars with GitHub Action workflow?

Tags: github-actions

Following [this article](http://rocket-science.ru/hacking/2019/08/19/use-github-ci-for-elixir-projects) and using [this help document](https://help.github.com/en/actions/automating-your-workflow-with-github-actions/workflow-syntax-for-github-actions#jobsjob_idservices), I am trying to get RabbitMQ started as a service for my job. The container starts, but the environment variable interpolation does not appear to be working.

Here is my workflow:

```
name: Test & Publish

on:
  push:
    branches: 
      - master

jobs:
  test:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest

    services:
      rabbitmq:
        image: rabbitmq
        ports:
          - 5672/tcp
        env:
          RABBITMQ_USER: guest
          RABBITMQ_PASSWORD: guest
          RABBITMQ_VHOST: "/"

    steps:
      - uses: actions/checkout@v1
      - uses: actions/setup-node@v1
        with:
          node-version: 12
      - run: yarn
      - run: ./scripts/test-all.sh
        env:
          RABBITMQ_HOST: rabbitmq
          RABBITMQ_PORT: $❴❴ job.services.rabbitmq.ports['5672'] ❵❵

  publish-npm:
    needs: test
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - uses: actions/checkout@v1
      - uses: actions/setup-node@v1
        with:
          node-version: 12
          registry-url: https://registry.npmjs.org/
      - run: yarn
      - run: yarn semantic-release
        env:
          NODE_AUTH_TOKEN: ${{secrets.npm_token}}
```

The issue is `RABBITMQ_PORT` part. I modified my code to print out the value of

```
console.log(`amqp://${process.env.RABBITMQ_HOST}:${process.env.RABBITMQ_PORT}`)
```

... and I get this in the logs:

```
amqp://rabbitmq:$❴❴ job.services.rabbitmq.ports['5672'] ❵❵
```

... which is wrong. The RabbitMQ container seems to have started successfully, and I see it mapped the port: `5672/tcp -> 0.0.0.0:32768`, so if the interpolation were correct, I would expect to see

```
amqp://rabbitmq:32768
```

Yet the docs don't appear to be doing the interpolation any differently than I am doing, so I'm confused as to what the issue is.

Answer (score 0):

My problem was copy/paste.

I pasted in

```
$❴❴ job.services.rabbitmq.ports['5672'] ❵❵
```

when it should've been

```
${{ job.services.rabbitmq.ports['5672'] }}
```

The curly braces are a different character code:

```js
var first = '❴';
var second = '{';

console.log(`${first.charCodeAt(0)} is not the same as ${second.charCodeAt(0)}`);
//=> "10100 is not the same as 123"
```